# Where-Object comparison does not execute: Get-ChildItem : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: powershell

I want to get all *.ddl files with the Name System.ComponentModel.Annotations from all files/folders. I am a PS newbie. The recursive part is copy/paste and should work. I just changed the filtering.

```
Get-ChildItem Where-Object { [Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($_.FullName) -eq 'System.ComponentModelAnnotations'} -Recurse |
ForEach-Object {
try {
 $_ | Add-Member NoteProperty FileVersion ($_.VersionInfo.FileVersion)
  $_ | Add-Member NoteProperty AssemblyVersion (
      [Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($_.FullName).Version
  )
} catch {}
$_
} |
Select-Object Name,FileVersion,AssemblyVersion
```

**The Error I get is:**

```
  Get-ChildItem : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem Where-Object { [Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyNa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (C:\Repositories...backend\01.Code:String) [Get-ChildItem], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

What is wrong about the Where-Object comparison?

My latest code snippet:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.dll -Recurse |
Where-Object { try{ [Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($_.FullName).Name -eq 'System.ComponentModelAnnotations' }catch{$false}} |
Add-Member NoteProperty FileVersion -Value {$_.VersionInfo.FileVersion} -PassThru |
Add-Member NoteProperty AssemblyVersion -Value {[Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($_.FullName).Version} -PassThru |
Select-Object Name,FileVersion,AssemblyVersion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-ChildItem` and `Where-Object` are two separate commands. To compose a pipeline using both, use the pipe symbol `|` to route the output from one to the other:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.dll -Recurse |Where-Object { [Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($_.FullName).Name -eq 'System.ComponentModelAnnotations' } |ForEach-Object { ... }
```

It might be worth noting that you can skip the `ForEach-Object` command completely and pipe the output to `Add-Member` - you just need to add the `-PassThru` switch to make sure it feeds the modified object back down the pipeline:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.dll -Recurse |
  Where-Object { [Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($_.FullName).Name -eq 'System.ComponentModelAnnotations' } |
  Add-Member NoteProperty FileVersion -Value {$_.VersionInfo.FileVersion} -PassThru |
  Add-Member NoteProperty AssemblyVersion -Value {[Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($_.FullName).Version} -PassThru |
  Select-Object Name,FileVersion,AssemblyVersion
```

Comment: thx for the recurse fix :P

Comment: thx it works considering the query, just I am getting assembly errors but thats another bug... ah my original Code has the try catch block down there... but now I am filtering and calling GetAssembly and in the filter I can`t use a try catch right?

Comment: @HelloWorld sure, you can do anything you want: `... |Where-Object {try{[Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($_.FullName).Name -eq 'System.ComponentModelAnnotations'}catch{$false}} |...`

Comment: that is nice. Would not compile is c# :P

Comment: @HelloWorld Think of a scriptblock `{...}` passed to `Where-Object` as an _un-named simple script function_ that takes one arbitrary object as input (`$_`) and outputs a _truthy_ value, or a _falsy_ value (no output = falsy). Once you realize that, you'll see that you can do _anything_ inside the filter block :)

Comment: You have any idea why the literal code is being written in the output instead of the value?: Name                                  FileVersion                AssemblyVersion                                                
----                                  -----------                ---------------                                                
System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll $_.VersionInfo.FileVersion [Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($_.FullName).Version     You find my latest code snippet appened in my original question!